# I want to trim every string between double quotes to 16 characters

Tags: regex, powershell

In Powershell, I have a string of this form:

```
"abcdefghijk","hijk","lmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghij"
```

Assuming that I know how to escape a character (thus, if I were actually to write it including the string markers):

```
"`"abcdefghijk`",`"hijk`",`"lmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghij`""
```

... how would I trim anything between double quotes to only 16 characters?

The expected output is therefore:

```
"abcdefghijk","hijk","lmnopqrstuvwxyza"
```

I thought this:

```
% {$_ -replace "([^\`"]{16})([^\`"]+)", "$1"}
```

would match any relevant blocks as *two* backreferences, one of length 16 and one of unlimited length, and return only the first. However, that just removes everything of length 16 or more, resulting in:

```
"abcdefghijk","hijk",""
```

This isn't what I expected at all! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You forgot to escape `$`.

Comment: Regex is not a good solution to this problem. What about `'"abc\"defghijk","hijk","lmnopqrstuv"'`? Clearly, in this string, that middle double quote is meant to be escaped, though what syntax you would use for escaping is an open question. Or what about just `'"abcdefghijk","hijk","lmno",yzabc"'`, which has unbalanced double quotes? Your question is just the tip of the iceberg of potential problems with the text. What you probably really need is a compiler (tokenizer/lexical analyzer + parser/syntactic analyzer that generates an abstract syntax tree), or to avoid the problem of parsing text.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is as simple as this: change the double quotes around $1 to single quotes:

```
-replace "([^`"]{16})([^`"]+)", '$1'
```

It is a bit counter-intuitive, but here is the reason behind it: when you use a pair of double quotes, `$1` is interpreted as a variable name and interpolated into its content, which is empty in this case, before it even reaches the regex engine.

Or, you can escape the `$` as well:

```
-replace "([^`"]{16})([^`"]+)", "`$1"
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following which should be pretty close to what you're trying to do:

```
(\w+)\W+(\w+)\W+(\w+){16}
```

https://regex101.com/r/kfEAFl/1

Here you have the three groups and you can join them in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example to do it without regex:

```
$longArray = @("1221111111111111111111111111", "213")
$shortArray = $longArray.ForEach{$_.ToString().PadRight(16, " ").SubString(0,16)}
write-host $shortArray
# Writes 1221111111111111 213
```